# Auto-mapper class object with nested multiple class objects

Tags: c#, automapper

I have used auto-mapper to map single class object which is working fine, say example

```
class_source{
 string a;
 int b
}

class_destination
{
 string a;
 int b
}
```

now what I have viewModel based on multiple class object as

### Source

```cs
public class WebSyncSummaryEntity
{
    public Web_AppFormsEntity AppForms { get; set; }

    public Web_EBS_SyncEntity EBS_Sync { get; set; }

    public Web_SyncAuditLogEntity SyncAuditLog { get; set; }
}
```

### Destination

```cs
[DataContract]
public class WebSyncSummaryView
{
    [DataMember]
    public Web_AppForms AppForms { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public Web_EBS_Sync EBS_Sync { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public Web_SyncAuditLog SyncAuditLog { get; set; }
}
```

how I can map to equivalent class object

I have tried in following code to map but error

```
public IList<WebSyncSummaryView> GetWebSyncSummary()
{
    IList<WebSyncSummaryView> _WebSyncSummaryView = null;

    IList<WebSyncSummaryEntity> _WebSyncSummaryEntity = _WebSyncCoreObject.GetWebSyncSummary();


    if (_WebSyncSummaryEntity != null)
    {
        var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.CreateMap<WebSyncSummaryEntity, WebSyncSummaryView>();
        });

        IMapper mapper = config.CreateMapper();

        _WebSyncSummaryView = mapper.Map<IList<WebSyncSummaryEntity>, IList<WebSyncSummaryView>>(_WebSyncSummaryEntity);
    }

    return _WebSyncSummaryView;
}
```

### Error

```
 "Error mapping types.\r\n\r\nMapping types:\r\nWebSyncSummaryEntity ->  WebSyncSummaryView\r\nApp.Entities.WebSyncSummaryEntity -> App.WebServices.DataContract.WebSyncSummaryView\r\n\r\nType Map configuration:\r\nWebSyncSummaryEntity -> WebSyncSummaryView\r\nApp.Entities.WebSyncSummaryEntity -> App.WebServices.DataContract.WebSyncSummaryView\r\n\r\nProperty:\r\nSyncAuditLog"}
```

Error mapping types.

```
Mapping types:
IList`1 -> IList`1
System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[[App.Entities.WebSyncSummaryEntity,  App.Entities, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]] ->  System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[[App.WebServices.DataContract.WebSyncSummaryView, App.Services.Contracts, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the Line

```
_WebSyncSummaryView = mapper.Map<IList<WebSyncSummaryEntity>, IList<WebSyncSummaryView>>(_WebSyncSummaryEntity);
```

To

```
_WebSyncSummaryView = mapper.Map<IList<WebSyncSummaryView>>(_WebSyncSummaryEntity);
```

There is no need to tell AutoMapper the source type. You try to map the IList<>, but you only want to map WebSyncSummaryEntity. Just tell the Mapper what for an result you want and the rest comes from the voodoo of AutoMapper ;)

Comment: So the convention changed in newer release of automapper?

Comment: I don't know since what version its supported, but it works in v4, too.

Comment: no same error again.... {"Error mapping types.\r\n\r\nMapping types:\r\nList`1 -> IList`1\r\nSystem.Collections.Generic.List`1[[App.Entities.WebSyncSummaryEntity, App.Entities, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]] -> System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[[App.WebServices.DataContract.WebSyncSummaryView, App.Services.Contracts, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]"}

Comment: @toxic I usually use arrays as destination but i thought it will work with an IList<> too. `mapper.Map<WebSyncSummaryView[]>(_WebSyncSummaryEntity).ToList()` works for me

Comment: no luck. error again.... {"Error mapping types.\r\n\r\nMapping types:\r\nList`1 -> WebSyncSummaryView[]\r\nSystem.Collections.Generic.List`1[[App.Entities.WebSyncSummaryEntity, App.Entities, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]] -> App.WebServices.DataContract.WebSyncSummaryView[]"}

Comment: need to add cfg.CreateMissingTypeMaps = true;

Answer (score 0):

found answer

```
 public IList<WebSyncSummaryView> GetWebSyncSummary()
    {
        IList<WebSyncSummaryView> _WebSyncSummaryView = null;

        IList<WebSyncSummaryEntity> _WebSyncSummaryEntity = _WebSyncCoreObject.GetWebSyncSummary();


        if (_WebSyncSummaryEntity != null)
        {
            var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.CreateMissingTypeMaps = true; //............... missing this
                cfg.CreateMap<WebSyncSummaryEntity, WebSyncSummaryView>();
            });

            IMapper mapper = config.CreateMapper();

            _WebSyncSummaryView = mapper.Map<IList<WebSyncSummaryEntity>, IList<WebSyncSummaryView>>(_WebSyncSummaryEntity);


        }
```